# gparted installed on OpenSuse shows all file system types as greyed out except for hfs

Tags: filesystems, opensuse, gparted

I have had this problem before and fixed it, but I don't recall how I did it and I did not record it (sadness :( )

I have all the requisite commands installed on OpenSuse to support gparted's efforts in creating any of the supported file systems. I recall that the problem was that gparted could not find the commands, in any event all the file systems are greyed out in the context menu except for the legacy hfs partition which only supports < 2gb. Even extfs2-extfs4 are greyed out.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Yes - I am running gparted with root privs through gnomesu.

Comment: Make sure all the filesystems are installed, search them in yast and install them or reinstall them. Also check the MD5 of the disk, it could be a bad disk.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried booting with a Linux Live CD / Gparted Live CD to see if this happens still?

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to modify a mounted partition?  Unmount it and then try running gparted.

Answer (score 0):

I've installed:

```
gilberto@SUGEP-DMASI:~> rpm -qa|egrep 'gparted|ntfs'
ntfs-3g-2009.4.4-3.2.1.i586
ntfs-config-1.0.1-291.1.i586
gparted-0.4.7-1.pm.1.2.i586
ntfsprogs-1.13.1-109.2.i586
gilberto@SUGEP-DMASI:~>
```

However when trying to use it from the menu item like you, it was grayed out. The problem occurs because it runs with the user's settings and not with root's. The workaround is:

1. Start a user terminal
2. From the user terminal became root (don't forget the signal):

   ```
   gilberto@SUGEP-DMASI:~> su -
   Password: 
   SUGEP-DMASI:~ # gparted
   ======================
   libparted : 1.9.0
   ======================
   ```